# Pygame: run a function only one time even if it is in a while loop

Tags: python, pygame

In my pygame script, I have a function to work with some images that I have to use in a `while` loop. The problem is that I only want to run the function once for each image. So, I want to run `self.convert_img(self.img_one)` once, then proceed to `self.convert_img(self.img_two)` and so on, untill all images are processed. Afterwards, I would like the function to stop, such that I can change the scene.

Here is a mock of my code right now:

```py
import pygame

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.count = 5

        # Load Images
        self.img_one = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "img_one.png"))
        self.img_two = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "img_two.png"))


    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
      
            img_one_transorm = self.convert_img(self.img_one)
            img_two_transorm = self.convert_img(self.img_two)
            ## img three transform


            self.clock.tick(30) 

    def convert_img(self, arg1):    
        self.window.blit(arg1, convert_img_rect)
        
        pygame.display.update()

        if self.count > 0:
            ## convert image function
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but could you set a variable to False before your while loop, and then after your convert_image() set it to True, and have an if checking that variable. So even though it's in a loop it would only run when that variable is set the way you want.

Comment: why not do it before the loop instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a count that increases by one then a bunch of if statements
like:

```
if count == 1:
    img_one_transorm=self.convert_img(self.img_one)
    count+=1
elif count == 2:
    img_two_transorm=self.convert_img(self.img_two)
    count+=1
```

did i understand this correctly?